# Name of distribution with pdf $r\exp(-r^2/2)1_{[0,\,\infty)}(r)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Is there a name for the distribution with pdf $$f(r) = r\exp(-r^2/2), \ \ r\ge0$$

?

It's not quite Exponential, not quite Normal, nor Half-Normal, I can't find any distribution I know of that this could be. Does it have some standard name?

Context:
I'm working through a question in probability that gives iids $X,Y \thicksim N(0,1)$, and $R,\,\Theta$ as the corresponding polar coordinates for $R \in [0, \infty), \Theta \in [0, 2\pi)$, so

$$ X = R\cos(\Theta), \ Y = R\sin(\Theta)$$

Working out the joint pdf of R and Theta, I get

$$f_{\Theta}(t) = 1/(2\pi) $$
$$f_R(r) = r\exp(-r^2/2)$$
In their respective domains

Which both seem like valid pdfs, give $R$ and $\Theta$ independent and $\Theta \thicksim U[0, 2\pi)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A $\sigma=1$ [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution).